# how to delete existing file from my local api folder on put method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

this is the following code i am using for image upload.its working fine.but the problem is i  want to delete the existing file from my local project api folder(Image) on updating the existing image(put method).`

```
[Route("api/Products/PostProductImage")]
        public Task<IEnumerable<string>> PostProductImage(int id)
        {
            if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                string fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/");

                MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fullPath);
                var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                    var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
                    {
                        var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                        Product product =db.Products.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Id==id);
                        if (product == null) {
                            return "product not found";
                        }
                        product.ProductImage = File.ReadAllBytes(info.FullName);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return "File uploaded successfully!";
                    });
                    return fileInfo;
                });
                return task;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "Invalid Request!"));
            }
        }`
```

so what changes i want to make in put method for checking the image that is existing or not in my image folder and save to db.
this is how my images are saving in [Image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efCxm.png)

thanks ebk

Comment: just confirming, you mean to check if Image exists into Image folder, if it exists you want to save it into db?

Comment: @ Prateek Deshmukh my oroblem is on updating  the existing image. i want to delete the existing  from my local folder called Image

Comment: so you can check like, if(File.Exists(i.LocalFileName)) { File.Delete(i.LocalFileName);}.. sorry for any typo as I replied from my mobile.

Comment: @ Prateek .thank you bro.its working for me.can you help me to do some validation before saving the image to db. like size(MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //Size = 1 MB) and extension of ".jpg", ".gif", ".png".thanks...

Answer (score 0):

@ebk check below codes.

// Code to check if file exists and then delete

```
if(File.Exists(i.LocalFileName)) 
{ 
      File.Delete(i.LocalFileName);
}
```

//Code the check extenstion

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(i.LocalFileName);
if(ext==".jpg" || ext ==".gif" || ext ==".png")
{
    //code
}
```

//Code to check file length

```
var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
var fileSizeInBytes = info.Length;
```

if this help you can mark it as solved :)

Comment: everything is working fine except extension check.
always ext coming as null.bcz i.LocalFilename is like BodyPart_ec0d2cd2-c29d-4171-a0ea-eedb08498237.how can we fix that